# AJAX not working on Django and returning 500 Error

Tags: jquery, django, ajax, django-views

I'm trying to send an AJAX request from my template that takes you to a url and runs the view function. However, I'm getting a 500 Error in my console. The error in Django log says: `TypeError: delete_appointment() missing 1 required positional argument: 'appointment_id'` My view is also using a custom decorator, all required code is below:

**Decorator**

```py
def user_has_delete(func, redirect_url="Home:Deny"):
    def wrapper(request, *args, **kwargs):
        if request.user.is_anonymous:
            return redirect(redirect_url)
        if request.user.is_authenticated:
            if not request.user.is_denier:
                return redirect(redirect_url)
            else:
                return func(request, *args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper
```

**URL Pattern**

```py
path('Vet/DenyAppointment/<int:appointment_id>', views.delete_appointment)
```

**View**

```py
@user_has_delete
@never_cache
def delete_appointment(request, appointment_id):
    appointment = get_object_or_404(Appointments, pk=appointment_id)
    appointment.delete()
    return redirect('Dashboard')
```

**Template Portion**

```html
{% for appointment in appointments %}
                        <div class="col-sm-12 col-lg-8 AppointmentDiv offset-sm-0 offset-lg-2 Space-b-sm">
                            <h2>{{ appointment.fullDate }}</h2>
                                <ul>
                                    <li>{{ appointment.title }}</li>
                                    <li>{{ appointment.day }}</li>
                                </ul>
                            <button type="submit" class="theme" id='{{ appointment.id }}' onclick="deleteAppointment({{ appointment.id }})">Delete Appointment</button>
                        </div>
                    {% endfor %}
```

**AJAX**

```js
<script>
            function deleteAppointment(appointmentId) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: '/Vet/DenyAppointment/' + appointmentId,
                    type: 'GET',
                    success: function(response) {
                        window.location.href = "/Dashboard";
                    }
                });
            }
        </script>
```

Comment: Why aren't you looking at your django server console to see the error trace? If you're getting a 500 error on the frontend it means your django app is crashing and producing a crash log. Probably if you look in your browser's network tab, you can also see the body of the response which will contain the crash log (assuming you're running django in DEBUG mode). 
Also your view is returning a redirect but that's not what an API response handler should do, it should always return a JSON response with success/error messages.

Comment: @dirkgroten I updated the question with the response from django log, sorry I forgot to post it and I did try to track it myself but couldn't figure it out.

Comment: @dirkgroten actually the problem seems to be in the decorator. But I can't seem to fix it.

Comment: aren't you missing `@wraps(func)` above the `def wrapper` line?

Comment: @dirkgroten yeah just figured that out but I haven't dealt with decorators that take additional parameter so I can't figure out how to configure my decorator

Comment: you mean the additional `redirect_url="Home:Deny"`? that looks fine since you set a default value. To set another value, just pass it to your decorator `@user_has_delete(redirect_url="some_other_url")`

Comment: @dirkgroten no, I want an additional param say appointmentID to be passed to my view? The one being sent to the url by AJAX

Comment: you're doing that correctly

Answer (score 0):

Fixed. I wasn't sending data in my AJAX just appending the appointment id in url. Then I needed to configure my decorator to accept additional parameters.